# Unpredictable input name in embedded visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, inline-visualforce

I am embedding a VisualForce page with a form and some inputs in a standard page layout. My form mark-up:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="ContactControllerExt" action="{!init}" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" doctype="html-5.0">
    <apex:pagemessages />

    <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!showAssignPanelB}">
        <apex:form >
            <apex:selectList id="area" size="1" label="Area">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!regionSelectList}" />
            </apex:selectList>      
            <apex:commandButton value="Assign" action="{!assignContact}"/><br/>
            <input type="text" name="reason" placeholder="Reason" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Not Approved" action="{!mediaBNotApprove}"/><br/>
        </apex:form>   
    </apex:outputpanel>
</apex:page>
```

If I replace the text input field with:

```
<apex:inputText id="reason"/>
```

the element renders as:

```
<input type="text" name="j_id0:j_id28:reason" id="j_id0:j_id28:reason" />
```

and I don't know how to look for that name in the page parameters in the controller. The `<select ...>` element also renders with an unpredictable name like `j_id0:j_id28:area`

How can I get the rendered names more predictable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Short answer

Use the value attribute of the select list to bind your select list to a controller property, it'll then be accessible to apex code, without needing to look for it in the page parameters.

`<apex:selectList value="{!yourControllerVar}" ...`

#### Suggested Reading

Data binding is a fundamental feature of Visualforce and is very helpful to understand.  You can read more about it in the [Visualforce API Docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index.htm) (search for "input") which sadly doesn't do a great job on the subject, but will hopefully get you going.

Comment: Hey! Waaay easier than picking around for form data in HTML headers. Thanks Ralph!

Answer (score 4):

The rendered names are going to show up like that when it converts the VF tags to HTML. You have a couple options:

- Use Visualforce Component references:

  - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm
- Use a [CSS selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) with something like jQuery that looks for an "ends with" like $('[id$="reason"]')

  - http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

Additionally, your use case might not necessarily require you to know the ID at run time. Is this something you could handle with data binding (as mentioned in @Ralph's answer)?